# Development Provisioning Profile appears ineligible, with no apparent repercussions

Tags: ios, xcode

So I recently created some provisioning profiles and am handling them manually in order to insure the correct use for push notifications. However, my Development profile appears under a heading of Ineligible, but seems to be accepted with no warnings or anything. Am I misunderstanding the meaning of eligible/ineligible in this situation? In the screenshot, you can see which profile is for distribution and which is for development. The fully crossed out one is just the wildcard

[image: Screenshot of possible selections]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this profile are made under another distribution cert which is not use in your project ?